# trouble passing object between Activities using intent parcelable extra

Tags: java, android

In my case, there is a listVIew in the first activity and by clicking on a listItem it redirects to another activity which allows to edit to edit details of the particular object item. once the selected item is edited in the second activity I want it to be updated in the first activity as well. I have used parcelable extra to pass data between two activities.

The first activity passes data to the second activity correctly but when it comes to updating the listView in the first activity using updated data in the second activity it throws a NullPointerException saying that the received object is null.

Please help me figure this out. thanks in advance.

**Parcelable object class**

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Movie implements Parcelable {
    private String title;
    private int releasedYear;
    private String director;
    private String cast;
    private int rating;
    private String review;
    private boolean favourite;


    public Movie(String title, int releasedYear, String director, String cast, int rating, String review) {
        this.title = title;
        this.releasedYear = releasedYear;
        this.director = director;
        this.cast = cast;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.review = review;
    }

    public Movie(String title, int releasedYear, String director, String cast, int rating, String review, boolean favourite) {
        this.title = title;
        this.releasedYear = releasedYear;
        this.director = director;
        this.cast = cast;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.review = review;
        this.favourite = favourite;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getReleasedYear() {
        return releasedYear;
    }

    public void setReleasedYear(int releasedYear) {
        this.releasedYear = releasedYear;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public String getCast() {
        return cast;
    }

    public void setCast(String cast) {
        this.cast = cast;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getReview() {
        return review;
    }

    public void setReview(String review) {
        this.review = review;
    }

    public boolean isFavourite() {
        return favourite;
    }

    public void setFavourite(boolean favourite) {
        this.favourite = favourite;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.title);
        dest.writeInt(this.releasedYear);
        dest.writeString(this.director);
        dest.writeString(this.cast);
        dest.writeInt(this.rating);
        dest.writeString(this.review);
        dest.writeByte(this.favourite ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
    }

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        this.title = source.readString();
        this.releasedYear = source.readInt();
        this.director = source.readString();
        this.cast = source.readString();
        this.rating = source.readInt();
        this.review = source.readString();
        this.favourite = source.readByte() != 0;
    }

    protected Movie(Parcel in) {
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.releasedYear = in.readInt();
        this.director = in.readString();
        this.cast = in.readString();
        this.rating = in.readInt();
        this.review = in.readString();
        this.favourite = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Creator<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Movie(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movie[size];
        }
    };
}
```

***First activity***

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.movietracker.database.CoreDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.movietracker.database.Constants.TABLE_NAME;
import static com.example.movietracker.database.Constants.TITLE;

public class EditMovie extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int REQ_COE = 1;
    CoreDatabase database;
    List<Movie> movies;

    Movie movieReturn;

    RelativeLayout layout;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQ_COE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                movieReturn = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("movieReturn");
                movies.add(movieReturn);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_movie);

        layout = findViewById(R.id.edit_relative_layout);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.edit_listView);
        movies = new ArrayList<>();

        database = new CoreDatabase(this);
        String query = "select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + " order by "+ TITLE + " ASC";
        Cursor cursor = database.getData(query);
        retrieveData(cursor);
        System.out.println(movies.size());

        MovieArrayAdapter adapter = new MovieArrayAdapter(this, movies);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EditMovie.this, EditMovieItemView.class);
                intent.putExtra("movie", movies.get(position));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                movies.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                System.out.println(movies.size());
            }
        });
    }

    public void retrieveData(Cursor cursor){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String title = cursor.getString(1);
            int year = cursor.getInt(2);
            String director = cursor.getString(3);
            String cast = cursor.getString(4);
            int rating = cursor.getInt(5);
            String review = cursor.getString(6);
            boolean favourite = cursor.getInt(7) > 0;

            movies.add(new Movie(title, year, director, cast, rating, review, favourite));
        }
    }
}
```

***Second Activity***

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.movietracker.database.CoreDatabase;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

import java.util.List;

public class EditMovieItemView extends AppCompatActivity {
    CoreDatabase database;
    Movie movie;
    String pickedDate, defaultTitle;
    String updatedTitle, updatedDirector, updatedCast, updatedReview;
    int updatedYear, updatedRating;

    CheckBox favourite;
    TextInputLayout title, year, director, cast, review;
    NumberPicker yearPicker;
    RatingBar rating1, rating2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_movie_item_view);

        database = new CoreDatabase(this);

        favourite = findViewById(R.id.edit_fav_checkbox);
        title = findViewById(R.id.edit_movie_title);
        year = findViewById(R.id.edit_movie_year);
        year.getEditText().setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter(1895, 2021)});
        director = findViewById(R.id.edit_movie_director);
        cast = findViewById(R.id.edit_movie_cast);
        rating1 = findViewById(R.id.edit_ratingBar1);
        rating2 = findViewById(R.id.edit_ratingBar2);
        review = findViewById(R.id.edit_movie_review);
        yearPicker = findViewById(R.id.edit_year_picker);

        yearPicker.setMinValue(1895);
        yearPicker.setMaxValue(2021);

        yearPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                pickedDate = String.valueOf(picker.getValue());
                year.getEditText().setText(pickedDate);
            }
        });

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){
            movie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("movie");
        }

        title.getEditText().setText(movie.getTitle());
        year.getEditText().setText(String.valueOf(movie.getReleasedYear()));
        director.getEditText().setText(movie.getDirector());
        cast.getEditText().setText(movie.getCast());
        review.getEditText().setText(movie.getReview());
        if (movie.getRating() <= 5){
            rating1.setRating(movie.getRating());
            rating2.setRating(0);
        } else {
            rating1.setRating(5);
            rating2.setRating(movie.getRating() - 5);
        }
        favourite.setChecked(movie.isFavourite());

        defaultTitle = title.getEditText().getText().toString();
    }

    public void updateMovie(View view){
        updatedTitle = title.getEditText().getText().toString();
        updatedYear = Integer.parseInt(year.getEditText().getText().toString());
        updatedDirector = director.getEditText().getText().toString();
        updatedCast = cast.getEditText().getText().toString();
        updatedReview = review.getEditText().getText().toString();
        updatedRating = (int) (rating1.getRating() + rating2.getRating());
        database.updateAllData(updatedTitle, updatedYear, updatedDirector, updatedCast, updatedRating, updatedReview, favourite.isChecked(), defaultTitle);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        movie.setTitle(updatedTitle);
        movie.setReleasedYear(updatedYear);
        movie.setDirector(updatedDirector);
        movie.setCast(updatedCast);
        movie.setRating(updatedRating);
        movie.setReview(updatedReview);
        movie.setFavourite(favourite.isChecked());

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("movieReturn", movie);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: movieReturn = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("movieReturn"); from first activity. Are you sure it's getIntent()? not data?

Comment: @March3April4 Sorry I'm not sure I got your point.

Comment: The intent you passed back via second activity will be received on your onActivityResult's 'Intent data' parameter. Just change the getIntent() to data, and I think it'll just work.